# How to secure PHP API from unauthorized AJAX calls (Phonegap mobile app)?

Tags: php, ajax, api, cordova, security

I want to make Phonegap application, in which I will use PHP API and AJAX calls to it for communication.

The problem is security - when I make AJAX calls to my PHP API - the address is visible for anyone who can read js files and they can easily manipulate the data.
I am thinking of two things that can be useful, but still not what I am looking for.

1. CSRF token generated by the PHP API - yes, but to get the token in the app, I still have to make a request to the API, which again is visible and can be duplicated/manipulated.
2. Uglify the js files, which is good for production, but it's not bringing the real security I want.

So the question is - how to secure my PHP API from unauthorized AJAX calls and allow only calls from my application?

Comment: Oh, so very very many duplicates there are for this. I'll try to find one. Short answer: You can't. Authenticate the user instead.

Comment: It's impossible to fully prevent a client from beeing modified, hijacked, cloned or abused. This is something you need to be aware of. The only thing you can rely on is serverside validation.